# php counter, Warning: fopen(clickcount.txt): failed to open stream

Tags: php, error-handling, counter

i copied a code from http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/3409885/button-click-counter-in-php, it counts how many times i click t submit. but every 20/40 clicks it gives this error: Warning: fopen(clickcount.txt): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\Users\nieke\Dropbox\wamp\wamp64\www\periode2\niek\spel2\klikspel.php on line 17.
this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Klik</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="klikspelstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <?php

  function clickInc()
{
  $count = ("clickcount.txt");

  $clicks = file($count);
  $clicks[0]++;

  $fp = fopen($count, "w") or die("Can't open file");
  fputs($fp, "$clicks[0]");
  fclose($fp);

  echo "<h3>aantal munten = $clicks[0]</h3>";



}
  ?>
  <div id="header">
    <center>
      <?php
           if(isset($_POST['knop'])){
            clickInc();
          }
      ?>
    </center>
  </div>
  <div id="kliknop">
    <center>
      <form action="" method="POST" name="knop">
        <input type="submit" name="knop" value="werken">

      </form>
    </center>
  </div>
  <?php

  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try putting the file somewhere other than your DropBox folder and see what happens

Comment: THANKS! it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not using a Dropbox directory. The problem is likely Dropbox sync.